# ¿Cómo manejar elementos eliminados?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, base-de-datos, sequelize

Estoy diseñando una base de datos para una tienda y hay una tabla llamada Ventas, esta tabla contiene los elementos vendidos. Pero esta tabla solo contiene las llaves foráneas de una de los productos.

[image: Diagrama de la base de datos]

¿Esto es correcto? Si esto es correcto ¿Cómo lo puedo manejar con sequelize? Porque habrá que hacer una comprobación si el id del producto no está en la tabla de Products entonces debe estár en la tabla Deleted Products

```js
class Sales extends Model {

  static associate(models) {
    this.hasOne(models.Products, { as: 'product', foreignKey: 'product' });
  }

  static config(sequelize) {
    return {
      sequelize,
      tableName: SALES_TABLE,
      modelName: 'Sale',
      timestamps: false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: los productos borrados no deberían ser seleccionables para venta

Comment: por lo general no eliminas productos solo le das existencia o stock es decir dentro de tu producto agregas una columna existencia de tipo boolean ya con esto sabes que si esta en 0 no hay o una tabla stock para los productos que si el stock es 0 no se muestre en caso de si recupere cuantos ahi adicional es para agregar modelos tallas o colores...

Comment: Hola @DavidFernándezFlores los productos eliminados no son almacenados para vender, son almacenados para mantener un historial de las ventas en caso de que el producto haya sido discontinuado

Comment: No seria mas conveniente añadir en la tabla de productos un campo adicional donde solo se indique que el producto ha sido descontinuado. Así no tienes que eliminar registro, ni copiar nada en ninguna otra tabla.  Tampoco se si sea la mejor practica.

Comment: Yo también lo considero mala practica, estoy de acuerdo con @Cesarin , no creo que sea buena practica mover un registro de una tabla a otra y tratar de mantener la "relacion", sería mas practico el campo adicional.